# create_engine in sqlalchemy not working in python 3.6 runtime for aws lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, sqlalchemy, aws-lambda, python-3.6, amazon-linux

I successfully tested pandas, numpy, and sqlalchemy in an Amazon Linux docker image using python 3.6. I was able to import, use, and connect to a database in the virtual environment using `create_engine` from the `sqlalchemy` module in python 3.6.

I then exported all the dependencies and built a python deployment package to run it in AWS Lambda but for some reason I keep getting an error for `create_engine` in lambda.

> module 'sqlalchemy' has no attribute 'create_engine': AttributeError

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sqlalchemy
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("DB_URI")

    return "Hello world!"
```

However, if I simply comment out the line where I call `create_engine`, I get my "Hello world!" response.

I don't get why `create_engine` is not working in this environment when it worked perfectly fine in the identical docker environment. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I had a rookie mistake when I was zipping up my file and didn't use the `-r` option which meant only the top level of my python module folders where getting zipped up. This explains why I wasn't getting an import error but none of the actual methods were working.

So to reiterate, the solution was adding the `-r` option to my `zip` operation to add all the files recursively:

`zip -r package.zip *`